# У меня есть radiogroup в котором есть несколько radiobutton.Как их запускать с помощью

Tags: java, android

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (R.id.radioButton == checked)
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Правильно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }else {
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Неправильно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
    });
    }
// Почему checked ошибка???Как мне выбрать ???
```

Comment: Потому, что вы сравниваете int с bollean. Вам это сама IDE должна говорить даже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша строка кода

```
 if(R.id.radioButton == checked)
```

непонятна. Вы сравниваете тип `int` с некой переменной `checked`. Так как ваша переменная не инициализирована, компилятор и выдает ошибку. А вообще, если вы хотите проверить выбрана ли `RadioButton`, то делать это нужно так

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
if(rb.isChecked())
//если выбрана
```